# Loading external data using JSON for JQTouch

Tags: json, jqtouch

I am trying to load some external data into a JQTouch app using JSON. My problem is I don't know what js to use and where to put it.

My html is very simple - a few divs for the pages in the app.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> google.load("jquery", "1.4.2"); </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqtouch/jqtouch.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> $.jQTouch(); </script>
    <script src="javascripts/cricket.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "jqtouch/jqtouch.min.css";</style>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "themes/apple/theme.css";</style>
    <title>Cricket</title>

</head>
<body>

<!-- "Main Menu" -->
<div id="home" class="current">
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1>Cricket</h1>
</div>

<ul class="rounded">
<li class="arrow"><a href="#clubs">Clubs</a></li>
    <li class="arrow"><a href="#fixtures">Fixtures</a></li>
<li class="arrow"><a href="#twitter">Twitter</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="rounded">
<li class="arrow"><a href="#about" class="slideup">About</a></li>
</ul>


</div>


<!-- "Clubs" - Will contain the list of clubs -->
<div id="clubs">

<div class="toolbar">
        <h1>Clubs</h1>
        <a class="button back" href="#">Back</a>
</div>

<div id="clubslist">   

    Loading....

</div>


</div>

<!-- "Fixtures" - Will contain the list of fixtures -->
<div id="fixtures">
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1>Fixtures</h1>
    <a class="button back" href="#">Back</a>
</div>

<ul class="rounded">
    <li>Loading....</li>
</ul>

</div>

<!-- "Twitter" - Will contain the tweets -->
<div id="twitter">
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1>Twitter</h1>
    <a class="button back" href="#">Back</a>
</div>

<ul class="rounded">
    <li>Loading tweets....</li>
</ul>

</div>


<!-- "About" - Will contain info about the app/contact -->
<div id="about">
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
</div>
just some text
</div>
```

Then this is the script that I think I need to use to load the external data (from clubs.php).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $.getJSON('http://www.mydomain.com/clubs.php', function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(i,item){
                $('clubslist').append('<li>' + item.club_name + '</li>');

           });
    });

     </script>
```

My question is where do I need to putthis and how does it get triggered? 
I think I need to put this in a separate JS file (I have already got one called cricket.js which i linked to in the head of the html file). Then I assume I need something to trigger the JS to run... like PageAnimationEnd or similar?

For what it's worth, this is what the clubs.php returns

```
{"posts":[{"post":{"club_id":"1","club_name":"ABC Cricket Club","club_postcode":"AB12 3DE"}},{"post":{"club_id":"2","club_name":"Beston Cricket Club","club_postcode":"NG1 9XY"}}]}
```

My ideal situation is that when the user clicks on the 'Clubs' link on the menu page, this fires the page animation where the user then sees 'Loading'. In the background, the Javascript is fired, retrieves the data from clubs.php and then appends it in to the #clublist div.

I think I am close, but missing the final finishing touch. All suggestions appreciated!
Tom

Answer (score 0):

In my pages I do the following, in this example I am pulling a table from a backend script.

```
  function prevOrders()
  {
  $("#chkPrevOrd").html('Please wait')  
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://"+document.domain+"/store.php",
        data: { method: "prevOrders"},      
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: ajaxTimeout,
        success: function(data){
        if (data.prevOrders)
            {
            $("#prevOrderStatus").html(data.prevOrders);
            $("#chkPrevOrd").html('Update')     
            }               
            },  
         error: function() {
        alert('This is taking too long. You could try again now, or wait and try again later.'); 

            }
 });     
  }
```

`#prevOrderStatus` is a DIV on this page, `#chckPrevOrd` is just a button to let the user know what is happening. you would JQT.Goto('cointainer div for #chkPrevOrd') to go to this page if `#chkPrevOrd` was actually on a different page.

Comment: Great, thanks for this, i'll give it a go. Am i right in thinking you actually format the table html in the php file, then pass the finished html table to the app?